# put values from query into array

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I need values from my database to plot a graph. 
I have multiple lines I want to plot on the same graph.
I need the values, for each line, in the following form, for as many different $dates there are in the database:

```
$graph_points1 = array(array($date, $value), array($date, $value), array($date, $value));
```

I have a query to get the data from the database:

```
$data = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM `wp_graph_info` ORDER BY DATE ASC"));
```

If I use the following code:

```
foreach($data as $datas){
$list_name = $datas->list_name;
$date = $datas->date;
$value = $datas->subscriber_count;
if($list_name == 'line1'){
$result = array(array($date,$value));}}
```

print_r($result); will give:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 2015-05-16 [1] => 131 ) ) 
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 2015-05-17 [1] => 133 ) ) 
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 2015-05-18 [1] => 137 ) )
```

which is almost what I want. 
I need to have the results as:

```
$graph_points1 = array(array(2015-05-16, 131), array(2015-05-17, 133), array(2015-05-18, 137));
```

how to I put it in the above form?

Also I can't plot the date on the x-axis. How do I only retrieve the 'day' value  so I have:

```
$graph_points1 = array(array(16, 131), array(17, 133), array(18, 137));
```

Also if there a way to loop through all th $list_names (I have 7 different lists, so my graph will plot 7 lines) or do I need to use an if() statement for each one?

Comment: do you mean: array('2015-05-16' => '131') ??

Comment: I don't really understand the `print_r` is the same as what you want?

Comment: because it's the same what you wantnow,  I agree with @Daan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = [];
foreach($data as $datas){
  $list_name = $datas->list_name;
  $date = $datas->date;
  $value = $datas->subscriber_count;
  list($year, $month, $day) = explode('-', $date);
  $result[$list_name][] = array($day,$value);
}

echo "<pre>";var_dump($result);echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: amazing! Thanks.Is there a way to loop through all the $list_names (there are 7) or do I need to write if() statements for each one?

Comment: I'd simply put the list_name as a key of the array. I'll update the script, one sec